# How to send a request with file upload in flutter retrofit

Tags: flutter, retrofit

I'm using flutter retrofit package
and I need to implement a request as shown in attached postman screenshot

[image]

this is what I do, but it didn't work

```
  @override
  @POST('/update/document')
  @MultiPart()
  Stream<double> uploadDocument(@Part() int id, @Part() File document);
```

the problem was that the file "document" not added to parameters list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `name` parameter inside your `@Part` annotation.

```
  @override
  @POST('/update/document')
  @MultiPart()
  Stream<double> uploadDocument(@Part(name:"id") int id,
                                @Part(name:"document") File document);
```

Comment: Thank you Miftakhul
How can I get the progress of uploading the file as stream